# jQuery "unsupported pseudo: required" only in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

In my javascript I have this jquery

```
$("#report_config_modal_13 :disabled:required")
```

In chrome and firefox this works fine but on IE11 it gives the error

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: required
```

What would be causing this and is there an alternative way to do the same thing that will work in IE11? This issue only seems to have come up after I updated jquery 2.2.3 to 3.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You just change your selector like as below the example code.**

it supported IE and other browsers.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("input[required]:disabled").each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).addClass('class1')
  });

  $("input[disabled]").each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).addClass('class2')
  });

  $("input[required]:not(:disabled)").each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).addClass('class3')
  });

});
```

```css
.class1 {
  background: red;
}
.class2 {
  background: blue;
}
.class1.class2 {
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
}
.class3 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input placeholder="textbox" type="text" disabled="" required="">
  <input placeholder="textbox" type="text" disabled="" >
  <input placeholder="textbox" type="text"  required="">
  <input placeholder="textbox" type="text" >
</form>
```

**-- Thanks --**

Comment: `$("input[required]:disabled")` was just what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Yea it's one of logic for selecting an element CSS or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

As we all known, the id attribute must be unique within a document. So, you could get the special elements by the [id selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_id.asp) (using the specific id), then check the attribute value. like this:

```
if ($("#input1").attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
    $("#input1").addClass("class1");
}
```

and

```
<input placeholder="textbox" class="input" id="input1" type="text" disabled="" required="">
```

If you want to select multiple elements, you could use [class selector or element selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp), like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".input[required]:disabled").each(function (index, el) {
            $(this).addClass('class1')
        });

        $(".input[disabled='']").each(function (index, el) {
            $(this).addClass('class2')
        });

        $(".input:not([disabled])").each(function (index, el) {
            $(this).addClass('class3')
        });
    });
</script>
<form action="#">
    <input placeholder="textbox" class="input" id="input1" type="text" disabled="" required="">
    <input placeholder="textbox" class="input" type="text" disabled="">
    <input placeholder="textbox" class="input" type="text" required="">
    <input placeholder="textbox" class="input" type="text">
</form>
```